# Jetpack Compose Modal Navigation Drawer - make scroll-able

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-material3

How does one make a ModalNavigationDrawer scroll-able in Jetpack Compose / Material3?

Tried using `LazyColumn` within the `ModalDrawerSheet` content, but get the error: `@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function`

Example MainActivity class (based on example from [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#ModalNavigationDrawer(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.material3.DrawerState,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,kotlin.Function0))) - **UPDATED** with `LazyColumn` implementation that compiles, runs, and even works now:

```
package com.example.testnavdrawaer

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.material3.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import com.example.testnavdrawaer.ui.theme.TestNavigationDrawerTheme
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class CountdownMenu(index: Int, name: String) {
    var index: Int = index
    var name: String = name
}

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            TestNavigationDrawerTheme {
                MainScreen()
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(DrawerValue.Closed)
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    // dummy list of menu items for example
    val menuItems: List<CountdownMenu> = MenuItems()

    val selectedItem: MutableState<CountdownMenu> =
        remember { mutableStateOf(menuItems[0]) }

    ModalNavigationDrawer(
        drawerState = drawerState,
        drawerContent = {
            ModalDrawerSheet(
                drawerContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                drawerContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer,
                content = {
                    LazyColumn {
                        items(menuItems) { item ->
                            NavigationDrawerItem(
                                label = { Text(item.name) },
                                selected = item.index == selectedItem.value.index,
                                onClick = {
                                    selectedItem.value = item
                                    scope.launch { drawerState.close() }
                                },
                                colors = NavigationDrawerItemDefaults.colors(
                                    unselectedContainerColor = Color.Transparent,
                                    unselectedTextColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                                    selectedContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer,
                                    selectedTextColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer,
                                ),
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(NavigationDrawerItemDefaults.ItemPadding)
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
        },
        content = {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(16.dp),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = if (drawerState.isClosed) ">>> Swipe >>>" else "<<< Swipe <<<",
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onBackground
                )
                Spacer(Modifier.height(20.dp))
                Button(onClick = { scope.launch { drawerState.open() } }) {
                    Text("Click to open")
                }
            }
        }
    )



}

fun MenuItems(): List<CountdownMenu> {
    val menuItems = mutableListOf<CountdownMenu>()
    for (i in 1..26) {
        menuItems.add(CountdownMenu(i, "Option " + i))
    }
    return menuItems
}
```

Comment: What is CountdownMenu?

Comment: In my case **LazyColumn** works as well!

Comment: Have you tried adding *@Composable* to your MenuItems() function? I believe you might need to remove the return functionality as well and it should work then.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti - helper class that didn't make the copy/paste cut.  Added above MainActivity above.

Comment: @ArthurKasparian - tried incorporating the `MenuItems()` directly within the code (it's just building the example menu items for testing) & separating the entire content within `TestNavigationDrawerTheme{}` above into a separate `@Composable` function.  Alas, same error on build.

Comment: @Anubis94 - where did you add the `LazyColumn{}` block?

I'd think it should go at beginning of content slot above - just above the `menuItems.forEach` line, but that doesn't work

Comment: Yes as @gazer said, I don't see where a LazyList was used in the code provided above to be getting that error, is AS specifying a line/file?

Comment: @gazer [srouce code](https://pastebin.com/8qa1qSQ6)

Comment: Thanks @Anubis94 - looks like I need to fix the `LazyColumn` call

Comment: @gazer Have you got it?

Comment: @Anubis94 - close.  Code compiles and runs now, but doesn't actually scroll.  Revised code above - any thoughts?  (And yes, I'd break up some of those functions in real code...)

Answer (score 0):

Code above now works.  Thanks to @Anubis94 for example code to compare against.

Issues resolved:

- Needed to manually import `androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items`
- Initial errors in the use of `items(menuItems) { item ->` block above
- Added example of how to change colors in the `ModalNavigationDrawer`